# Unable to change my desktop background Windows 7 Starter

Tags: window

I can't change my desktop background in Windows 7 Starter on a Dell Inspiron mini. It just stays blue with a windows logo.

Answer (score 1):

If u have windows 7, right click on your desktop and select 'personalize'. In that personalization window select desktop background and change the desktop wallpaper. (you can select the picture location by using the drop down menu on the top). Alternatively you can open the desired picture in 'windows photo viewer' (ie the default Microsoft picture viewer) and right click on that picture and choose 'set as desktop background'.

Or if u have windows XP right click on the desktop, select properties. Click the 'Desktop' tab & choose the desired background wallpaper. You can use the above alternative method in windows XP also.

If you have windows 7 starter edition ( if u have dell inspiron mini, probably it has) unfortunately you cannot change the desktop background.

Please follow this link :--

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/281-desktop-background-change.html

Answer (score 0):

Acutally this wouldn't work for windows 7 starter. Microsoft has blocked this function for the starter edition. Since i consider myself to be an it pro i use ultimate of course.

Maybe [this](http://www.techspot.com/guides/264-change-wallpaper-on-windows-7-starter/) helps you to get an other background for your dekstop anyway.